# Select id's where the column values are equal and not equal

Tags: mysql, sql

here is an example table:

```
id  |  column1  |  column2 
thr |  0        |  100
pop |  100      |  100
poi |  0        |  100
```

the output should be

```
id 
thr
poi
```

above table id's have different column values

another output should be

```
id
pop
```

with common column values

Comment: I'd recommend a `WHERE` clause...

Comment: `select id from your_table where column1 != column2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Different: SELECT id FROM table_name_here WHERE column1 != column2;
Same: SELECT id FROM table_name_here WHERE column1 == column2;
```

Comment: But I have 10 columns. how to do it for 10 columns

Comment: For 10 columns you will need to list all of them: c1 == c2 && c2 == c3 && c3 == c4 ...

Answer (score 0):

Use `WHERE` clause with conditional operators.

For selecting id(s) having same `column1` and `column2` values. Then,

**Query**

```
select `id` from `your_table_name`
where `column1` = `column2`;
```

For selecting id(s) having dfferent `column1` and `column2` values. Then,

**Query**

```
select `id` from `your_table_name`
where `column1` <> `column2`;
```